# Problemas con la IP por usar Selenium webdriver (JAVA)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ip, extensión-google-chrome

estoy usando Selenium en un proyecto Springboot con Java. Está corriendo con Tomcat, en localhost, usando Chrome como webdriver.

Funciona perfecto, pero luego de unos días, noté que cuando navego como usuario (desde mi computadora y otras conectadas a la misma red de internet) no puedo acceder a determinados sitios, me aparecen errores que no son de HTML, sino que tienen que ver con seguridad de los sitios.
Ej:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si cambio la red, y uso los datos del celular, puedo ingresar perfecto, por lo tanto asumo que me banneron la IP o algo por el estilo.

Tengo las siguientes preguntas:
Si antes de correr el proceso, habilito un vpn en mi máquina esto sirve? 
o tendría que instalar una vpn via plugin en el chromeDriver y meter código en el proyecto para que sirva? Algo así:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/[your local name]/Documents/chromedriver");

    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addExtensions(new File("/Users/[your local name]/Documents/extension_1_2_5.crx"));

    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
    System.out.println("Opening extension");
    driver.get("chrome-extension://**aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm**/dhc.html");
```

Y la segunda pregunta es:
Como logro recuperar mi ip? como hago para que los sitios dejen de tirarme esos errores?

Gracias!

Comment: Si te han baneado la IP porque estés haciendo accesos no autorizados (ya sea por exceso de solicitudes, o por solicitudes incorrectas, sean maliciosas o no, o por cualquier otro motivo), es probable que si sigues usando tu programa acaben baneando también la IP de salida de tu VPN, Si es tu VPN de empresa puede que te metas en un lío por hacer eso. Para que el sitio te quite el ban a tu IP te tendrás que poner en contracto con el administrador de ese sitio. Si lo que estás haciendo es legítimo te podrá poner en una lista blanca para que puedas continuar haciendo lo que sea con selenium

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, el sitio que me "baneo" no lo estuve scrapeando. Yo estimo que viene por el uso de selenium, pero no estaría del todo segura, sinceramente.